# Why am I getting 'ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique:' when the record seems to be unique?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, activerecord

I am trying to test that 2 relationships are created when a user requests to follow another user. know I have a uniqueness constraint so that multiple relationships cant be created, but I can't work out why I'm getting this error msg - as far as I can tell the relationship is unique.. ??

error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique:         ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: relationships.follower_id, relationships.followed_id: INSERT INTO "relationships" ("created_at", "followed_id", "follower_id", "state", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
            app/models/relationship.rb:19:in `block in request'
            app/models/relationship.rb:18:in `request'
            test/models/relationship_test.rb:59:in `block (2 levels) in <class:RelationshipTest>'
            test/models/relationship_test.rb:58:in `block in <class:RelationshipTest>'
```

models/relationship_test:

```
  test "should create active and passive user relationships" do
    assert_difference 'Relationship.count', 2 do
      Relationship.request(users(:firstname), users(:firstname2))
    end
  end
```

models/relationship:

```
  # makes sure 2 relationships are created otherwise none are created. 
  def self.request(user1, user2)
    transaction do
      relationship1 = create!(follower: user1, followed: user2, state: 'pending')
      relationship2 = create!(follower: user2, followed: user1, state: 'requested')
    end
  end
```

fixtures/relationship:

```
one:
  follower: firstname
  followed: firstname3

two:
  follower: firstname
  followed: firstname4

three:
  follower: firstname3
  followed: firstname

four:
  follower: firstname2
  followed: firstname
```

fixtures/user:

```
firstname:
  name: Firstname Surname
  email: firstname.surname@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>

firstname2:
  name: firstname2 Surname2
  email: firstname2.surname2@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>

firstname3:
  name: firstname3 Surname3
  email: firstname3.surname3@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>

firstname4:
  name: firstname4 Surname4
  email: firstname4.surname4@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>
```

db/seeds:

```
# Following Relationships
users = User.all
user = users.first
following = users[3..50]
followers = users [4..40]
following.each { |followed| user.follow(followed) }
followers.each { |follower| follower.follow(user) }
```

not sure if there's other relevant code I should include.. these are all snippets of each file

**EDIT:** migration:

```
class CreateRelationships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :relationships do |t|
      t.integer :follower_id
      t.integer :followed_id

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :relationships, :follower_id
    add_index :relationships, :followed_id
    add_index :relationships, [:follower_id, :followed_id], unique: true
  end
end

class AddStateToRelationships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :relationships, :state, :string
    add_index :relationships, :state
  end
end
```

Comment: Please provide the part of your database migration where you create the unique index on the `relationships` table.

Comment: added them in just now!

Comment: I'm still really stuck on this - been looking at it for hours. Really appreciate any help anyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked it out, so silly and frustrating!

```
Relationship.request(users(:firstname), users(:firstname2))
```

was trying to create a relationship where one already existed in the relationship fixtures:

```
four:
  follower: firstname2
  followed: firstname
```

I saw this at the start but didn't realise tests were smart enough to consider all fixture elements like that - i wasn't specifically referencing relationship 4 so I didn't think the test would care that it existed. I also didn't realise activerecord would complain about fixtures like that - i thought it just complained about the actual code.. if any of that makes sense!

I created 2 new users (firstname5 and firstname6) in fixtures/users and changed the following code and the test passed:

Relationship.request(users(:firstname5), users(:firstname6))

One of these days I'll understand Rails! :s